# DevExpress VerticalGrid bound to the DefaultView of a DataTable

Tags: data-binding, ado.net, devexpress-windows-ui

BACKGROUND:
I've used the VerticalGrid in *unbound* mode for a few years, where I handle moving data between the editors and my data object using my own code.

Now I'm trying to use it in MultiRecord layout mode

```
Name: [           ] Name: [           ] Name: [           ]
Addr: [           ] Addr: [           ] Addr: [           ]
City: [           ] City: [           ] City: [           ]
```

and binding it to  the DefaultView of a System.Data.DataTable:

```
  vGridControl1.DataSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
  vGridControl1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
```

However, changes to a record are not being pushed out to the DataView *until the edited record loses focus*.

QUESTION:
Is there a way to put the grid into a mode where the datasource is updated as soon as the **cell** editor loses focus?  For example, if **Name** is edited, and the user moves to **Addr**, the datasource immediately reflects the change?

Answer (score 1):

You can to this in the ValidatingEditor event as below:

```
private void vGridControl1_ValidatingEditor(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs e)
    {
        vGridControl1.UpdateFocusedRecord();
    }
```

The following will update the field explicity in the data source without attempting to write the entire record:

```
        private void vGridControl1_ValidatingEditor(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BaseContainerValidateEditorEventArgs e)
    {
        var list = vGridControl1.DataSource as IList;
        var record = list[vGridControl1.FocusedRecord] as DataRowView;
        record[vGridControl1.FocusedRow.Index] = e.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there's a conflict if later rows in the grid have an `AllowNull = false` constraint on the underlying DataColumn. This `UpdateFocusedRecord()` approach pushes the entire record to the datasource, whereas I need to push only the current editor's value into the DataSource.

Comment: I'm appending the answer with a solution that updates only the focused field in the data source.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me some good help. vGridControl.FocusedRow  returns the correct object, but vGridControl.FocusedRow.Index returns 0, which is not the correct index of the column in question. However, vGridControl1.FocusedRow.Properties.FieldName or ..Properties.RowHandle get me to the right place in the DataRowView.

Comment: I have this now: var recordindex = vGridControl1.FocusedRecord;
            DataRowView drv = (vGridControl1.DataSource as DataView)[recordindex];
            drv[vGridControl1.FocusedRow.Properties.FieldName] = e.Value;